# Why does noTrimWrap not work in the following TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Wrap works, but need the spaces for better presentation, unfortunately it doesn't work with "noTrimWrap" :-(

I use Typo3 9.5.10

I hope someone can help me :-)

```
myTicker = CONTENT
    myTicker {
      wrap = |
      table = tx_myPlugin_domain_model_tick
      select {        
        pidInList = 31        
        max = 4
        selectFields = dbfield_1, dbfield_2
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj { 
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = dbfield_1

        20 < .10            
        20.field = dbfield_2

        noTrimWrap = |<div>+++ Neuer Eintrag: | +++</div>|
      }             
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COA` does not have a direct `stdWrap` on the root level. This should work though:

```
myTicker = CONTENT
myTicker {
  wrap = |
  table = tx_myPlugin_domain_model_tick
  select {        
    pidInList = 31        
    max = 4
    selectFields = dbfield_1, dbfield_2
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj { 
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = dbfield_1

    20 < .10            
    20.field = dbfield_2

    stdWrap.noTrimWrap = |<div>+++ Neuer Eintrag: | +++</div>|
  }             
}
```